# Float is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm getting a `float` object is not callable error when trying to do a calculation for force of gravity on a mass.

```
def grav():
    mass = float(input('Enter a mass[kg]: '))
    dist = float(input('Enter a distance from the surface of earth [m]: '))
    rad = 6.3781*10**6
    me = 5.97219*10**24
    gr = 6.67300*10**-11
    f = ((gr((me)*(mass)))/((rad)+(dist)**2))
    return f

grav()
```

It's giving the float error on the part where everything is being calculated

Comment: in line 7, you miss a symbol after *gr*

Answer (score 3):

```
gr((me)*(mass))
```

The above tries to call `gr` like it's a function.  It's just a constant.  There's no need for all of those parentheses, anyway.

```
gr * me * mass / (...)
```

You do have a bug in the denominator though.  You need to divide by `(rad+dist)**2`, not `rad + (dist**2)` (which you're doing now).

Altogether

```
f = gr * me * mass / (rad + dist)**2
```

That's all you need.

And if I can make a suggestion, make your variable names more self-documenting.  I can understand your code because I recognize the formula, but not everyone is going to have that advantage.

```
force = G * MASS_OF_EARTH * mass / (EARTH_RADIUS + distance_from_earth)**2
```

Easier to read, no?  You don't have to be *this* verbose, but too much is better than too little.  It can be tempting to over-abbreviate in scientific computing but I really advise against it.  Be terse when necessary but always be self-documenting.

Answer (score 0):

change the line 7 like

```
f = ((gr*((me)*(mass)))/((rad)+(dist)**2))
```

or you can simplify your formula with

```
f = gr*(me*mass)/(rad+dist)**2
```

it will work.

Comment: Your bottom edit is incorrect.  Division has a higher priority than addition.